# Valgrind version 3.16.1 - unrecognized command line option '-m64'

Tags: c++, makefile, valgrind, gnu, arm64

I'm trying to compile Valgring3.16.1 with aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (for xilinx zynq-mp board)
the ./configure stage passed ok.

when I run:
make CC= ..... /bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
I got this error:

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'

How can I fix it?

any help will be appreciated,
Tzipi Kluska

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change compiler or flags, you should do that when you run `configure`, not when you run `make`. Otherwise `configure` sees and detects a different environment than what you get with `make`.

Comment: Thank you!!! 
I put my CC flag when i run ./configre and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html) have the answer you ask for.

`-m64` is available for other architectures than AArch64.

If you need the "Machine-Dependent Options" you should read [AArch64](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) options.